# Make mongoose string schema type default value as blank and make the field optional

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a test schema with mongoose in nodejs like

```
testschema = mongoose.Schema({
         name:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    unique:true
  },
  image:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  category:{
    type:String
  },
});
```

How can i make the category field as optional and make it default to blank if not given by user?

I tried

```
 category:{
        type:String,
        optional: ''
      },
```

but when printing out the documents saved with the scheme it doesnt even shows the field category.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

What you most likely need here is to set the `default` value.

```
category: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
}
```

This makes the field somewhat optional, because if you don't set it, it defaults to `''`

Additionally, you can pass a **function** to generate a default value:

```
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
```

Note that we are passing `Date.now` here (not `Date.now()`), which is a function that returns the current timestamp.
This is equivalent to an arrow function like:

```js
default: () => Date.now()
```

### Setting defaults on Update

As mentioned by [user whoami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237613/whoami), mongoose only sets defaults **on insert.**

If you are using **mongoose 4.x and up** and **MongoDB 2.4.0 and up** you can opt-in to **setting default values on update too.**

All `update` and `findOneAndUpdate` queries also apply defaults when setting the `upsert` flag.

[Mongoose docs: The setDefaultsOnInsert option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#the-setdefaultsoninsert-option)

Comment: i was trying with the wrong command optional:' '. Not sure from where i got that. Anyways this is working thanks for the help. :)

Comment: upvote for the answer !! but please look into few conditions it does have as it seems to work on new inserts only unless you specify to work on updates as well, check these :  (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html) or (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433942/how-can-i-use-partialfilterexpression-on-a-mongoose-model/57434190#57434190)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to overcome this current limitation on the new inserts is just to place a default value when you are doing the post request. As in this sample code:

```
var category = req.body.category || 0;
```

That assuming the user hasn't touched the field, therefore its value is **null** by default.