# MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

when i send request from postman software to vs code then first time data is entered successfully in mongodb compass. when i try to send another data from unique name, email and phone then this error occures.

I dropped my database too many times but unable to solve my error.
I am sharing my error screenshot and code please look into this and help me.

[image]

Database connection code is:

```
 const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbname", {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB connected`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }}module.exports = { connectDB };
 connectDB();
```

Route and controller code is :

```
router.post("/admin/register", async (req, res) => {
    const { Name, Password, Phone, user_type, twofactor_code } = req.body
    try { let user = await User.findOne({ Phone })
        if (user) {
            return res.send("Phone have already")
        }

        user = new User({
            Name,
            Password,
            Phone,
            user_type,
            referral_code: await code_gen()
        })

        const token = await user.genAuthToken();

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.Password = await bcrypt.hash(user.Password, salt);

        user.save()
        res.status(200).send({ msg: "success", user, token })

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
        console.log(e);
    }})
```

mongodb model code is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);

var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    user_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },Phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10
    },
    Password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },      
    lk_name: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
        unique: true
    },
```

I checked the db collection and no such duplicate entry exists, let me know what I am doing wrong ?

I also checked this post but no help STACK LINK

If I removed completely then it inserts the document, otherwise it throws error "Duplicate" error even I have an entry in the name.

Comment: check my code there is unique :true   in        lk_name: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
        unique: true
    },

Comment: My bad for deleting my comment. Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/16067314/13505073

Comment: i tried this but nothing works same error is coming

Comment: What is `lk_name`? It's `null` in the item you are trying to insert which seems to conflict with another document that also has a `null` value for the field

Comment: Remove the `default: null` from `lk_name` if you don't plan to assign it on user creation.

Comment: You need to use a partialFilterExpression to make a nullable or optional field unique.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57434190/2282634