# How can I limit the number of admin roles to one in my schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

`schema.js`:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["user", "admin"],
    default: "user",
  },
})
```

I would like to set a rule where only 1 admin can exist at a time. I'm thinking I may need to use a custom validator but wasn't sure if there was a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this through Mongoose, you could create a unique index on `{role:1}` with the partialFilterExpression of `{role: "admin"}`.  That way any attempt to insert a second admin, or update an existing user to make a second admin will fail with a duplicate key error, but any other value in `role` will not be included in the index, so only "admin" would be unique.  This would be enforced by the database server.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59810471/2282634

Comment: I tried doing something like ```userSchema.index({ role: 1 }),
  {
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: { role: "admin" },
  };``` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: you may need to run syncIndexes if the collection already exists

Comment: Ah thank you. I ended up just deleting the document and refreshing, Also I had made a syntax error and it should be like: `userSchema.index(
  { role: 1 },
  { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { role: "admin" } }
)` and now it finally works

Answer (score -1):

To limit the number of admin roles to one in your MongoDB schema, you can use a combination of unique index and a validation function. Here's an example of how you can modify your `userSchema`:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
});

userSchema.index({ role: 1 }, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { role: 'admin' } });

// Add a pre-save hook to validate the number of admin roles
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified('role') && this.role === 'admin') {
    const isAdmin = await this.model('User').findOne({ role: 'admin' });

    if (isAdmin && !isAdmin._id.equals(this._id)) {
      const error = new Error('Admin is exist!!.');
      return next(error);
    }
  }

  next();
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

I hope this might help you.